# How to handle checkboxes when looping in HTML Service of Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am creating a web app with Google Apps script using checkboxes from MaterializedCss.com.
I encountered a problem with apparently my html scructure in relation to my checkboxes or my button.

I need that by clicking the button "SelectAll" all checkboxes are selected.

Now this button doesn't do anything, all checkboxes except first one are inactive when clicked. I can tick/untick only first checkbox.
And when I click on the rest of them it changes the first one to checked/unchecked.

```
 //a button from Materializedcss.com
<a class = "select-buttons waves-effect waves-light" id = "selectAll">Select all</a> 

   //Css style for this <a> tag  
    .select-buttons {
      height: 40px;
      width: 90px;
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: Transparent;
      text-decoration: underline;
      };


    <div class = "container">

        //collapsible element from MaterializeCss site
        <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header teal lighten-2"><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>1 step: choose employees</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
          <span>  

    <a class = "select-buttons waves-effect waves-light" id = "selectAll">Select all</a> 

    //looping thru my backend function using scriptlets
    <? for (var i = 0; i < loopNamesForSidebar().names.length; i++) {?>
        <label for = "check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" id = "check"/>
         <span>

         //to collect elements together in rows
          <div class="collection">     
          <a href=" <?= loopNamesForSidebar().calendars[i] ?>" class="collection-item"><?= loopNamesForSidebar().names[i]  ?> </a>
             </div>
             </span>

             <? } ?>
             </label>
          </span>
         </div>
        </li>
      </div> <!--closed container -->

//Javascript part
<script>

//on page load, run function
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    //when clicking a button "select All"
    document.getElementById("selectAll").addEventListener("click", selAll)

     //make all checkboxes checked
function selAll() {

  //getting all checkboxes
  var allCheckboxes = document.getElementById("check")

  //make them all "checked"
  allCheckboxes.checked = true

  }
 };
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out already, `getElementById()` only ever returns one element. Instead you want to use a DOM method which returns a collection of elements (like `getElementsByClassName()`), and loop through all the elements to check each one. Try replacing these lines:

```
//getting all checkboxes
var allCheckboxes = document.getElementById("check")

//make them all "checked"
allCheckboxes.checked = true
```

with:

```
var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
for(var i=0; i<allCheckboxes.length; i++) {
   allCheckboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```

You'll need to add a "check" class to your checkboxes for this.

Comment: OMG that works! Thank you! I have done almost the same before but I put the class name like document.getElementsByClassName(".check") with a period which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, the value passed to the `id` attribute of an element is meant to be a unique identifier. Thus, the invocation `document.getElementById("check")` will only return a single element (probably the first element with the given id).

What you need is to set the `class` attribute. Multiple elements can share the same class which allows you to target multiple elements using a given class.

You can then leverage [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to retrieve the desired list of elements.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have done that too before and checkboxes were all active. So that's not the main case. What bothers me is that the button meaning <a> tag is not doing anything with them.

Comment: Can I select all checkboxes by ID (IDs) or Id is only for one element (or the first one in my case)?